# Can I connect 3-core electrical wire to a 2-socket load?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ventilation, fans, load

I am completely new and inexperienced with electrical work but wanted to learn how to DIY a very basic exhaust fan installation in my kitchen.
I built a hood that mounts onto a small window and bought a bare-bones exhaust fan that needs to be hooked up to an NYM-J 2x1,5mm 230V electrical cable (I live in Germany, for reference). One problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find that type of cable when I search in stores and online. I only found a 3-core NYM-J as pictured. I was hoping someone could help me out with a few things I've gotten stuck on while learning how to complete this project.

1. Which wire should I purchase and where can I find it? Will an H07RN-F 2x1,5mm work?
2. How do I join the wire to the 2-socket load seen in the picture? Do I need some kind of joining plug to connect to the wire?

I apologize for the naive nature of this post and appreciate your patience in advance.

[image]

Comment: those DIY who survived and still alive will call a electrician. For you the 3d wire (green.yellow) is a ground wire. The other 2 will insert and tighten with screwdriver, with power off at the breaker